# What could possibly be the reason why my CNN achieves abnormally high validation loss for some epochs?

Tags: neural-networks, convolution

I am training a CNN for a simple binary classification problem and for some reason, I am getting abnormally high validation_loss at some epochs while still achieving good validation_accuracy. [image] What am i doing wrong here?

[image]

I am trying to do a simple transfer learning using EfficientNetB0 as the base model. I am writing in Tensorflow + Keras.

Comment: What loss function does `validation_loss` measure?

Comment: binary_crossentropy. I'm doing a simple binary classification problem. Sorry forgot to mention abt that

Comment: Can you edit the post to include that information? And also include the model architecture that you're using?